# Refetching object when traversing relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In our app, we make use of multiple `NSManagedObjectContext` instances, one per thread created. So when I'm about to use any object, I always make sure that I got the object from the correct context by doing this.

```
object = (ObjectClass *)[[contextProvider contextForCurrentThread] objectWithID:[user objectID]];
```

Since I want to make sure the object is updated I go and refresh it:

```
[[contextProvider contextForCurrentThread] refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];
```

And my question is: If I want to traverse relationships from this object, i.e `object.someRelationship`, Should I also make sure that the relationship is in the current context, and refresh it? What would be the correct approach?. Refetching and refreshing every time is such a pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look into nested contexts and concurrency types. They won't solve your underlying problem but they are much better than what you already have.
2. You need policies. To me it seems that your software (without knowing it at all) is lacking structure. Structure comes with policies.
3. Even if you were to refresh your objects (all of them) all the time you have serious race conditions.

Without knowing the details of your app nobody will be able to suggest anything except "think about what you do" and "introduce policies".

Comment: Can you give me an example of one of those "policies"? I don't think the questions is broad, it's in fact very specific.

Comment: Read this blog post: http://thermal-core.com/2013/09/07/in-defense-of-core-data-part-I.html (it talks about policies about halfway through)